# Notion of Separability

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Notion of Separability

An irreducible polynomial $f\in F[X]$ is separable, if $f$ has no repeated root in a splitting field, if $f$ is not necessarily irreducible, then we call $f$ separable, if each of its irreducible factor is separable.

I don't understand the second part of this definition, does it mean that, if $f$ is reducible and the splitting field of $f$ is also $F$, then multiple roots are allowed or what ?

How is then $f(X)=(X-1)^2(X-2)\in\mathbb Q$ separable, although $1$ is a repeated root ?

Comment: $1$ is a repeated root of $f$ but $f$ is not *irreducible*.  Its irreducible factors $x-1$ and $x-2$ do not have multiple roots.

Comment: @GregoryGrant but then if $f$ is irreducible,and $f$ splits in a splitting field   say $E$ for example as $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^{r}(x-\beta)^n$, for $r,n\ge 2$, is then $E$ also a splitting field ?

Comment: In your question you assume $E$ is a splitting field and then ask if $E$ is a splitting field.  So I don't think that's exactly what you really wanted to ask.  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: @Gregory Grant sh.. I meant Is then $f$ now also separable ?

Comment: No if $r\geq2$ or $n\geq2$ then $f$ is not separable.  Note that this is impossible over $\mathbb Q$, all polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ are separable.

Comment: The definition of separability that I'm familiar with is the one that I think you would prefer: a polynomial $f\in K[X]$ (whether irreducible or not) is separable if it has distinct roots in a splitting field. Wikipedia seems to suggest that your definition is an older definition that has benefits for Galois theory, but "is no longer in use" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes I've seen that, but then my example in the question would be inseparable, (since $1$ is repeated, and there is nothing mentioned about the irreducible factors)

Comment: Your example illustrates the difference between the two definitions. With your definition, $f$ would be considered separable.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I don't understand your definition of separable.  What do you mean by "distinct roots in a splitting field"?

Comment: The point is $(x-1)^2(x-2)$ is separable because its irreducible factors $(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$ are separable.  I don't think there's any confusion between two definitions.

Comment: @GregoryGrant let $E$ be the smallest extension in which $f$ splits completely (which may be the trivial extension). Does $ f$ have distinct roots in this extension?

Comment: The alternative definition (ie that advanced by Wikipedia) says nothing about irreducible factors. A reducible polynomial is separable iff it has distinct roots in a splitting field. In this case, the splitting field is $\mathbb Q$ itself, and the polynomial has a repeated root, so it would not be considered separable.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to say "$f$ has distinct roots".  Any two different numbers are distinct.  So if $f$ has two roots somewhere, they are distinct.  So even a non-separable polynomial has "distinct" roots.  The issue is one of the multiplicity of the linear factors in an extension where $f$ splits.

Comment: Ok it doesn't just say "distinct roots," it qualifies that this specifically means "the number of its distinct roots is equal to its degree."  Secondly, I think that wiki page is wrong.  You have to assume $f$ is irreducible to define it that way.  Then define it for reducible to be all the irreducible factors are separable.  Can anybody produce an actual math textbook reference where it is defined as in the wikipedia page?